# Downloading text from webpages using Scrapy raises UnicodeError and text is not stored correctly

Tags: python, text, encoding, utf-8, scrapy

I am using a Scrapy crawler to download text from some webpages belonging to different companies and store the text in a csv file using a utf-8 encoding and with the format

'company','company number','extracted text'

My problem is that no matter how I try to take webpage char encoding into account, I always get a lot of UnicodeError's of the type

```
2014-08-26 13:43:13+0200 [scrapy] INFO: Encoding for page http://militaryaircraftspares.net/index.html is cp1252
2014-08-26 13:43:13+0200 [scrapy] INFO: UNICODE ERROR, in http://militaryaircraftspares.net/index.html error is 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xa0' in position 478: ordinal not in range(128)
```

therefore loosing a lot of data.
Furthermore, the final csv file (I implemented a pipeline that uses CsvItemExporter) is completely messed up: there are definitely more than 3 columns, overall, and I have some parts of the extracted_text ending up in the 'company' or 'company number' fields. As if some excape characters in the extracted_text are not properly recognized and produce a new line where it is not needed (that's my guess, at least).
I assume I'm doing something deeply wrong somewhere, but couldn't figure out where...
So here is the crawler's function that is supposed to do the work

```
def extract_text(self, response):
    """ extract text from webpage"""

    #checks whether the page is actually html
    if type(response) == scrapy.http.response.html.HtmlResponse:


        hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
        page_text = ' '.join(hxs.select("//body//p//text()").extract())
        current_encoding = response.encoding

        log.msg("Encoding for page "+response.url+" is "+current_encoding)

        item = CompanyText()
        item['co_name'] = self.co_name.encode('utf-8')
        item['co_number'] = self.co_number.encode('utf-8')

        if current_encoding != 'utf-8':
            try:
                decoded_page = page_text.decode(current_encoding, errors='ignore')

                encoded_page = decoded_page.encode("utf-8",errors="ignore")

                item['extracted_text'] = encoded_page
            except UnicodeError, e:
                log.msg("UNICODE ERROR, in "+response.url+" error is %s" % e)
                item['extracted_text'] = ''.encode('utf-8')
        else:
            item['extracted_text'] = page_text


    else:
        item = None
```

Comment: are you sure you need to be doing any encoding/decoding?

Comment: Well, not all webpages are in utf-8. Fore example the one I mentioned above in the error has cp1252.

Comment: as @PadraicCunningham implies, I would not recommend encoding the unicode strings you get out of `Selector`, I'd leave that to the CSV exporter which usually handles it fine

Comment: You're right, I got rid of all the encoding and decoding and left it all to CsvExporter. But, I still get some (although not as many as before) weird behaviour in the csv file: as if it sees an end of line where it shouldn't be. I even got rid of all special characters in the page_text string by splitting it and then dropping any non-alphanumerical substring. But the problem remains and the csv file is not what i expect it to be

Answer (score 0):

1. The output of selectors is always unicode, so you should join unicode.

   This:

   > ```python
   >    page_text = ' '.join(hxs.select("//body//p//text()").extract())
   > ```

   Should be:

   ```python
   page_text = u' '.join(hxs.select("//body//p//text()").extract())
   ```
2. Since `page_text` is unicode.

   This isn't needed:

   > ```python
   >    decoded_page = page_text.decode(current_encoding, errors='ignore')
   >
   >    encoded_page = decoded_page.encode("utf-8",errors="ignore")
   > ```
3. `CsvExporter` will try to get the `Field` `serializer`, which is a function that receives value as argument. Our default `serializer` is `_to_str_if_unicode`, and use utf8 as encoding.